# How to efficiently make network requests from launcher activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-networking

I have an app that has a series of activities let’s say A,B,C,D,E,F,G.
All these represent different screens and may have fragments.
Activity A is the launcher activity. In that activity I need to make a request to a server to fetch some data.
The data are displayed in a list and the user clicking the list can navigate to the other activities.
For all the other activities except the first for any network requests, I can do them once the user goes in the activity e.g. `onCreate`.
This way I won’t have too much requests unlike if I did a request `onResume`.
But if I follow the same approach for activity A, I’ll end up updating the data only if the user kills the activity.
I could make a request every X mins but I was wondering if there is some standard approach that could even be used by all activities.
Is there some standard update approach for this case?

Comment: once the data has been downloaded once how long before you expect it to be stale?  Periodic tasks that require a network connection can be done with a `JobScheduler` or an even higher abstraction called `WorkManager` that chooses the best solution based on API - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: @MarkKeen: I think for around 30+ mins. But why would I need the scheduler to update if the user never goes back to the launcher activity? What I am not sure is how to efficiently fetch data when user goes back to that launcher activity without making too many requests depending on the flow (e.g. as when having it  `onResume`)

Comment: why not just set an internal epoch (current time + 30mins) once first request is successful (store in shared preferences), check it each time the uses navigates to your launcher activity, (or however often you like in your app navigation) if passed, reload/update epoch, if not do nothing ..

Comment: @MarkKeen:If the user goes A->B->C and then C->B->A if the data are fetched `onCreate` then activity will show stale data. If I fetch the data `onResume` then I'll have network requests even on change of orientation, user switches app for a sec etc

Comment: @MarkKeen:Yes that could work. But how would approach be generalized for a) more than 1 network type of request in activity A and b) something that can be reused for the other activities? I think there should be some android design pattern for this issue

Comment: WorkManager is generalised ..

Comment: @MarkKeen:Seems overkill to me having some scheduling framework to update data the user might not even see

Comment: You don't have to repeat, it can be one shot  "These APIs let you create a task and hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate time." .. either way I suggest use of a `Service` of some kind.